# Run method async

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run some of my **custom** code asynchronously in **Powershell**. The following tries to check for updates in a background thread:

```
Function CheckUpdates($manager)
{
    . "$PSScriptRoot\..\commands\upgradecmd.ps1";

    $upgradeCmd = New-Object UpgradeCmd -ArgumentList $manager;
    [bool]$upgradesAvailable = $false;

    try
    {
        $Global:silentmode = $true;

        $upgradeCmd.preview = $true;

        Start-Job -ArgumentList $upgradeCmd -ScriptBlock { param($upgradeCmd) $upgradeCmd.Run(); };

        Get-Job | Receive-Job;

        $upgradesAvailable = $upgradeCmd.upgradesAvailable;
    }
    finally
    {
        $Global:silentmode = $false;
    }

    if ($upgradesAvailable)
    {
        WriteWarning "Upgrades detected.";
        WriteWarning "Please, run the upgrade command to update your Everbot installation.";
    }
}
```

The problem is that inside the job (in the **ScriptBlock**), PS doesn't recognize anything about my custom "Run()" method, so it doesn't know how to call it. I've tried to "include" the class in the job using the `-InitializationScript` parameter with little success.

After searching the web, it seems that the way to do this is using **PS Jobs**, there's no thread handling in PS or something like "async". The point is that I just want to run a method of some class of my PS code asynchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you dot source inside the scriptblock?

```
Function CheckUpdates($manager)
{
    try
    {
        $Global:silentmode = $true

        $Scriptblock = {
            param($manager)
            . "<absolutepath>\upgradecmd.ps1"; #better to replace this with absolute path
            $upgradeCmd = New-Object UpgradeCmd -ArgumentList $manager;
            [bool]$upgradesAvailable = $false
            $upgradeCmd.preview = $true
            $upgradeCmd.Run()
            $upgradesAvailable = $upgradeCmd.upgradesAvailable;

            Return $upgradesAvailable
        }
        Start-Job -ArgumentList $manager -ScriptBlock $Scriptblock
        $upgradesAvailable = @(Get-Job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job) #This will probably not be so cut and dry but you can modify your code based on the return value
    }
    finally
    {
        $Global:silentmode = $false;
    }

    if ($upgradesAvailable)
    {
        WriteWarning "Upgrades detected.";
        WriteWarning "Please, run the upgrade command to update your Everbot installation.";
    }
}
```

I have added a `Wait-Job` as well before receiving it so your script would wait for the jobs to finish.